# Getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error when searching through my 2D array

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am working on a piece of code where a robot recursively searches through a maze to find the correct path to the end. I believe I have properly implemented the recursive function, however when I try to fill the 2D array in my main function I run into the following error:
Segmentation Fault (core dumped). I have shown my code below. Any help I could get would be helpful. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isValid(int x, int y)
{
    if(x >= 0 && x <= 6 && y >=0 && y <= 6)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

    int mazeGo(char maze[6][6], char solution[6][6], int x, int y)
    {
        char mazeFull [6][6] = 
        {
            {'.','#','#','#','#','#'},
            {'.','.','.','.','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
            {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
            {'.','.','.','#','.','.'},
            {'#','#','.','.','.','#'}
        };

        //checks to sse if the robot is at the goal
        if(x == 5 && y == 4 && isValid(x,y) == 1)
        {
            printf("Maze had been Solved");
            solution[x][y] = '.';
            return 1;
        }

        else if(x != 5 && y != 4 && isValid(x,y) == 1)
        {
            //Robot travels north
            if(mazeGo(mazeFull,solution,x,y-1) == 1)
            {
                solution[x][y] = '.';
                return 1;
            }
            //Robot travels East
            else if(mazeGo(mazeFull,solution,x+1,y) == 1)
            {
                solution[x][y] = '.';
                return 1;
            }
            //Robot travels south
            else if(mazeGo(mazeFull,solution,x,y+1) == 1)
            {
                solution[x][y] = '.';
                return 1;
            }
            //Robot travels west
            else if(mazeGo(mazeFull,solution,x-1,y) == 1)
            {
                solution[x][y] = '.';
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                solution[x][y] = '#';
                return 0;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }


    int main()
    {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      char solution[6][6];
      char maze [6][6] = 
        {
            {'.','#','#','#','#','#'},
            {'.','.','.','.','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
            {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
            {'.','.','.','#','.','.'},
            {'#','#','.','.','.','#'}
        };
        if(mazeGo(maze,solution,x,y) == 1)
        {
          for(int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
          {
            for(int c = 0; c < 6; c++)
            {
              printf("%c \n", solution[r][c]);
            }
          }
        }
        /*else
        {
          printf("There is no solution");
        }*/

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The recursion never ends and at some point the stack is full which usually ends with some crash. Put `printf("%d %d\n", x, y);` at the beginning of the `mazeGo` function and you'll see.

Comment: Surely in `isValid()` the `x <= 6` should be `x < 6` and the same for `y`. This will result in indexing `char solution[6][6]` out of array bounds.

Comment: An other problem is that you're transmitting the whole maze and solution as parameters by value which also will fill the stack very quickly, but with such a small maze that shouldn't be the main problem here. But on the other hand this might be the _actual_ cause of your problem. Try to modify your code and have `maze` and `solution` as global variables.

Comment: Aside `char maze[6][6]` is a parameter of the recursive function but is never used. Did you *intend* to use it instead of defining another `char mazeFull [6][6]` in each recursion (which won't inherit the previous population).

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes! That was the problem, thank you for the help. I was just wondering how I would end it. I thought the return statement in the function takes me out of the function, but since it does not how would I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your maze is an array of 6x6 that means the positions to elements are located in [0][0] to [5][5].

Your isValid function have a bug when it let x and y be equal to 6. Try the change bellow:

```
int isValid(int x, int y) {
    return (x >= 0 && x < 6 && y >= 0 && y < 6);
}
```

Comment: That's probably just _one_ problem.